# insert calculated field in pivot table based on previous row of one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I want to create a calculated field BookCnt_Diff which would be row1-row2 and if RPT DT = grand total then 0..  this data is the result of a query which looks back 6 months so I want to be able to refresh the data monthly.  I would also want the same Diff column for Shelf_cnt preferably between the originals

```
Values

 Rpt Dt           Book_Cnt     BookCnt_Diff       Shelf_Cnt 

 09/01/2012       5,604,552     15037            9,119,375 
 08/01/2012       5,589,515                      9,096,615 
 07/01/2012       5,576,289                      9,077,553 
 06/01/2012       5,590,771                      9,069,373 
 05/01/2012       5,586,510                      9,060,378 
 04/01/2012       5,572,887                      9,035,119 
 Grand Total     33,520,524                     54,458,413
```

On top of that when trying to get the getpivotdata to work the way I want so far was impossible... and m$ unhelp is so useful
thanks

*Not from OP*: Perhaps a help in showing result required:

[image: SU490037 example]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you ask. Its a little confusing. I understand you are trying to create a column which calculates the difference from month to month of `BookCnt`, but what does `RPT DT=grand total then 0` mean? Have you already created the pivot table before the data was ready?